# Suggest good addins-tools for visual studio .net(all the versions-2005-2008 etc)

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I  have seen an addin (3rd party tool) in Visual Studio .Net 2003 to display dataset(Dataset Visualizer) while debugging mode.

Now this feature is available as a bultin in Visual studio 2005.

This is really a helpful addin for VS2003 where it made the debugging task easy.But i was unaware of such tools till i found someone using it.

I appreciate someone can suggest such good 3rd party addins or tools which makes the devolopers task easy?

Thanks in advance

SC

---

**Duplicate question:** [What are some good usability addins for Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/do-you-have-any-recommended-add-onsplugins-for-microsoft-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Visual Studio Gallery](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com), it's the place to go for Visual Studio integration projects

Answer (score 2):

Resharper by jetBrains is a powerful static analysis tool - it can help you refactor code, and quickly navigate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do anything with WPF [Mole](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx) is great.

Also, the "XAML Power Toys" are pretty handy. (I'm a new user, so apparently I can only post 1 link, so you'll have to google for this one - sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The [LINQ to SQL Visualizer.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[WSCF](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/wscf)

A bit obsolete with WCF, but indispensable if you have to create old-style asmx webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Web Deployment Projects

Not really a 3rd party (it's from Microsoft), but you have to install it separately:

[VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx)

[VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en)