# Visual Studio ad-hoc tools and plugins

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

**Guys,**

I opened this question (I hope could help some others) but reading stackoverflow I find some really **interesting pearls of information** lost in the cloud. What do I mean? For example I was reasearching the Web for the best way to validate parameters in methods. I was breaking my head trying to find a nice, elegant way to do it, then I found a question about Code Contracts.

Then I found that many programmers are using the new **FWK 4.0 Contracts** and that blew up my mind ( I didn´t even know that exist).- I was trying to reinvent the wheel again.- So there are plenty of **plug ins, tools, addons, kits, frameworks, etc** and *not everybody are aware of all of them.*

Perhaps somebody is having a headache during the design of an application and a "well known" VS add on can help you.-

So what is that little tool that you can´t stop using and makes your development much more easy.

Three that I found (Im sorry if this is too newbie)

1. **NetReflector** (Sweet!)http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/
2. **VSDocman** (For documentation, free trial) http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html
3. **Code Contracts** (for parameter validation) http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

Comment: This should probably be made CW.

Comment: @Zombie, Im sorry what is CW?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969225/suggest-good-addins-tools-for-visual-studio-netall-the-versions-2005-2008-etc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080/what-are-the-best-visual-studio-addins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100420/hidden-features-of-visual-studio-2005-2008

Comment: Community Wiki - it doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: @MRFerocius: Click on "edit", check the "community wiki" box, and click the "Save Edits" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following plugins for Visual Studio:

- [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for Subversion
- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [CopySourceAsHtml](http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/) (useful for pasting code in emails when reviewing)

Comment: You just made my day, for a week I tried to use Visual Source Safe 2005 with VS2008 and I never been able to configure it properly (over internet) and all the people told me to use subversion, and is great to know this plug in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com)
- for C++: [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com)

Both not free, but definitely worth their price.

Comment: Great, I will take a look at it.