# "Must have" Visual Studio addons

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

So - this is a question to all the Visual Studio users out there - what addons do you use, and can't live without - and why ?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. That one compared Resharper vs Devxpress CodeRush vs Visual AssitX.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the previous comment. But of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080/what-are-the-best-visual-studio-addins

Comment: Duplicate, and if not, it should be community wiki.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you have any recommended add-ons/plugins for Microsoft Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/do-you-have-any-recommended-add-ons-plugins-for-microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: My favorite (next to ReSharper, of course) is the color theme editor extension!

Answer (score 11):

Just one: [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html)!

Can't live without it.

Comment: +1 for ReSharper. Also VisualJS.NET is great for ASP.NET developers.

Answer (score 5):

- Resharper or devexpress refactor (pro or express )
- .NET Reflector
- AnkhSvn
- Microsoft StyleCop

Answer (score 2):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) if you're using Subversion. It works amazingly well, and it doesn't mess with Visual Studio's brain-damaged source control bindings.

Comment: VisualSvn is cool but it is not free AnkhSvn 2 would be better :)

Comment: I had a hard time with AnkhSvn - not being able to connect to various repositories. Finally gave up, spent $49, and with VisualSVN, everything's perfect, the way it should always be!

Answer (score 2):

I use VisualSVN but I heard since v2.0 AnkhSVN is pretty solid, personally for $49 dollars it is a solution I already bought into and has *always* been stable.

Resharper is a must.

Aside from those two VS2008 provides everything I need. On VS2005 I use CoolCommands to get some things like 'Open Folder in Explorer' from solution explorer too.

I forget... I use Test-Driven.Net plugin to get the right click 'Reflector' and test coverage with NCoverExplorer for the rare times I use it, and the even more rare times when JetBrains implementation of NUnit via their Test runner doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) - absolutely the best and greatest addon there is - even in a **FREE FOR ALL** version ([CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)).

Next:  [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/DF3F0C30-3D37-4E06-9EF8-3BFF3508BE31) - free as well

Others: Only for specific topics, e.g. VisualSVN for Subversion access etc.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Assist X - Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any addons. VS is good enough.

Comment: well try resharper and you will change your opinion :)

Comment: I did try for a few months. It's great, but not needed really.

Comment: @Brian Liang We know VS is good.

Answer (score 0):

I knew someone would beat me to R#, without a doubt the best productivity add-on.

Other than that, AnkhSVN as an SVN client and that's pretty much it. IMHO VS2008 is an excellent IDE that doesn't need to many add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

Not an addon but it's manually installed like an addon and overlooked by a lot of developers: SP1 for VS2008. Finally adds background compilation! Also greatly improved Javascript editing.

Comment: Julian, excuse my ignorance, what do you mean by 'background compilation', not found any noticable difference between RTM and SP1 in this area.

Comment: In SP1, whatever you type is immediately compiled to check its validity. Any errors that would normally only surface when you compiled yourself (syntax errors, referencing undeclared variable, wrong types, etc) then show a red squiggle line underneath them. I really missed this feature coming from Eclipse/Netbeans, but it was finally added in SP1.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I think Resharper has given us this for a long time, but at least it in the base package now.

Answer (score 0):

These tool are very useful

1. [Outliner Power Toy](http://sourcecodeoutliner.codeplex.com/)
2. [Power Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DF3F0C30-3D37-4E06-9EF8-3BFF3508BE31)