# visual studio extensions not showing in main window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Studio and the extension functionality it has. I've recently downloaded some plugins such as Javascript Parser and they have installed just fine.

What I can't seem to find is how to add it to my main programming window in VS. I've tried googling but all I can find is how to install and uninstall extensions rather than showing me how to add the extension to my main window.

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddIn are great to improve productivity in VS. I myself use couple of Addin.

Every AddIn would have got it's own set of functionality and it's own window's. Specifically for Javascript Parser, you can open it by navigating to **View->Other Windows -> Javascript Parser** in menu bar in Visual Studio. I am attaching a screenshot from my system.

[image]

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/recommended-add-ons-plugins-for-microsoft-visual-studio) for couple of recommened VS AddIn.

UPDATE 1:

AddIn provide extension to VS, they are not limited to one window. So a AddIn like Resharper (see in attached Image) is in Menu Bar. Web essentials comes into work when you a open a css file which has link to image etc. So every AddIn would extend VS in certain way. How is it to be used, should be documented in AddIn documentation.

Quote From VisualStudio.com

> Visual Studio was built for extensibility to expand the functionality
>   of the IDE. Here are some examples of how you can extend the Visual
>   Studio IDE.
>
> Add new UI such as menu items and tool windows to add your own tools.
>   Extend the editor and our compilers to analyze and understand your
>   code. 
>   Extend Visual Studio Online and Team Foundation Server to
>   analyze information, manage the development workflow, or integrate
>   external development services. 
>   Integrate a new compiler and project type into Visual Studio to bring new     assets into your solution.
>   Distribute your tool with the Visual Studio shell even if your users
>   don’t have Visual Studio.

If you need more details please go through [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/643343/Visual-Studio-Add-Ins-In-Depth) & [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324611/Extending-Visual-Studio-Part-Creating-Addins) & [3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173496/How-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-Add-in-that-Launches)

Comment: Great thanks, I also have Web Essentials installed but can't see it in View->Other Windows, where else could it be?

Comment: Web essentials is a great tool for web developers and has got many features not limited to a extra window. You may refer to http://vswebessentials.com/ for more information on how to use them

Comment: So every extension I download for VS, if it has an extra window inside of it, would be found in view -> other windows?

Answer (score 0):

Simple question deserves a simple answer. **Simply put, extensions add menu items apparently at random, and not under the Extensions menu where you might expect them to be put.**

Eg: adding "Code Converter C# to/from VB.NET" to vs19. I had to use the convenient Search menus option (in form title bar). Also, I used the extension manager to disable/re-enable the extension, then I could see what had changed.

Comment: Thanks, I had an extension that wasn't showing up at all until I disabled and reenabled it.

Comment: @AndyD273 - thanks - you might consider an upvote for me then. I don't want Qdos, I just have the vague notion that sometimes when I try to help, my time is not wasted because by upvotes, I may reach more people. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Already did that! You happen to be -1 +1 at the moment. I don't know why the -1, but the +1 was me.